# Force jenkins to return stable build?

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins

We have 11 @tests which we call a test pack and each test pack gets populated with about 15 -20 individual tests.

We then split the @tests into 2 batches.

Batch one is test pack 1 -6 and batch two is from 7 - 11. We build these tests on jenkins each night concurrently. Batch 1 99% of the time returns stable.

Batch 2 99% of the time returns unstable even if the build was successful. We have a @test after test pack 11 that creates a report with failed tests.

Now when jenkins returns a build as unstable the @test generateReport doesnt "close" the report has been created however the bytes indicate 0kb thus tells me it never closed.

Is there a way to force jenkins to return stable state? Using java and Selenium

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Pipeline Jobs and Jenkinsfiles for your build process, you can manually set the build result.

The `currentBuild` variable is made available in any Jenkinsfile. The following is untested, but should give you a general idea

```
node {
    stages{
        stage('Test') {
            script {
                try {
                    # Run tests here
                } catch (e) {
                    # Determine if e indicates the expected test failures or something else
                    currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the above should mark the `Test` stage succesful; the rest of the build would continue as normal